# Simple C Pointer Clarification

Tags: c, pointers

I just started with working with pointers in C and I'm hung up on something simple. I want to make sure I understand it correctly.

Say I have something like this:

`int *buff;`

From what I read,

`*buff refers to the value that buff is currently pointing to`
`&buff refers to the address`

But what I'm stuck on is:

What does just "buff" refer to? Does it refer to the location of &buff in memory which points to the location of the value *buff?

Thanks a bunch! :3

-jtsan

Comment: The unary `*` and `&` operators are inverses of each other.  For all `x`, it's always true that `*(&x) == x`, and for all valid pointers `x`, it's always true that `&(*x) == x` (if `x` is not a pointer, then `*x` doesn't make any sense and is a syntax error; if `x` is an invalid pointer, then `*x` is syntactically valid but will result in undefined behavior at runtime).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`int *` means "a pointer to an int."  So, here, `buff` is a pointer to an int. To make things simpler, let's also say:

```
int x = 5; 
int *buff = &x;
```

`x`, an integer, is set to 5.
`&x` means "the address of x". So `buff` contains the address of `x`. For the sake of argument, let's say that `x` is stored at memory address 0x1000. So `buff` itself is also a number: 0x1000.

`*buff` means "the thing pointed to by buff," in this case 5.

`&buff` means "the address of buff": the address at which number `buff` itself is stored in memory.

I'd like to share a general technique that I used to learn how pointers work when I was starting out.

Get a big sheet of graph paper and lay it lengthwise on the table in front of you. This is your computer's memory. Each box represents one byte. Pick a row, and place the number '100' below the box at far left. This is "the lowest address" of memory. (I chose 100 as an arbitrary number that isn't 0, you can choose another.) Number the boxes in ascending order from left to right.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+--
|   |   |   |   |   | ...
+---+---+---+---+---+--
100  101 102 103 104  ...
```

Now, just for the moment, pretend an int is one byte in size. You are an eight-bit computer. Write your `int a` into one of the boxes. The number below the box is its address. Now choose another box to contain `int *b = &a`. `int *b` is also a variable stored somewhere in memory, and it is a pointer that contains `&a`, which is pronounced "a's address".

```
int  a = 5;
int *b = &a;
```

```
  a       b 
+---+---+---+---+---+--
| 5 |   |100|   |   | ...
+---+---+---+---+---+--
 100 101 102 103 104  ...
```

Now you can use this model to visually work through any other combinations of values and pointers that you see. It is a simplification (because as language pedants will say, a pointer isn't *necessarily* an address, and memory isn't *necessarily* sequential, and there's stack and heap and registers and so on), but it's a pretty good analogy for 99% of computers and microcontrollers.

You can extend the model for real four-byte `int`s too...

```
int a = 5;
char b = 2;
```

```
  a   a   a   a   b
+---+---+---+---+---+--
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 2 | ...
+---+---+---+---+---+--
 100 101 102 103 104  ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Given the declarations:

```
int value = 13;
int *buff = &value;
```

You're right:

```
*buff == 13
```

because `buff` points to `value` and that contains 13.

You're probably misunderstanding what `&buff` refers to; it is the address of the variable `buff`, and so the type of `&buff` is `int **`, a pointer to a pointer to an integer.  By contrast, the `&value` is the address of the variable `value`; it is of type `int *` (so the initialization did not need any cast - it is of the correct type to be stored in `buff`).

Plain `buff` is an `int *` or pointer to an integer.  It contains the address of the variable `value`.

Answer (score 3):

> *buff refers to the value that buff is currently pointing to

**Yes**

> &buff refers to the address

**No**. At least not if you're thinking what I think you're thinking. `&buff` does *not* refer to the address of what it's currently pointing to, `&buff` refers to the address in memory in which `buff` itself is located.

> What does just "buff" refer to?

`buff` refers to what you thought `&buff` was, i.e. the address of what `buff` points to.  The value of a pointer is the address of what it points to.

Here are some examples to help you out:

1. `int *buff;` -- declare *a pointer
   to int* which currently doesn't
   point anywhere
2. `int foo; buff = &foo;` -- point buff to the
   *address* of foo
3. `*buff = 5;` -- change the
   *contents* of what buff points to (foo) to 5
4. `int **buff_ptr = &buff;` -- declare
   a pointer to *a pointer to int*
   and point it at the address of 
   buff

Answer (score 3):

buff was declared as "pointer to int". using *buff is like saying "what buff points to", i.e the int value. using &buff is like saying "the address of buff", which is the address of the pointer, that points to int (another level of indirection).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that `*buff` refers to the location `buff` points to, but `&buff` refers to the address *of `buff` itself*. The address (`&`) of the data that `buff` points to (`*`) is `*&buff`, or more commonly just `buff`.

Good luck. Pointers are pretty tricky, but you look like you're on the right track.

Comment: Could you try using more words and less symbols to say what you're trying to say? Are you implying that the `*` and the `&` negate each other? I'm worried the current answer is confusing.